# Dynamically change the value of rows using JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have Created one vf page in which i am changing values dynamically of Table and it is changing the whole value of table, but i want to change values of particular row using javascript..

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="PricingOptionCalculatorCtrl" sidebar="false" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.extendedcss}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.Main}" />

  <!--  <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js"/>-->



<apex:form >
<style>

    body .bPageBlock .pbBody .labelCol{
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
    body .mainTitle{
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
    #minHandle, #maxHandle{
                width: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
    #minHandle1, #maxHandle1{
                width: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
    #minHandle2, #maxHandle2{
                width: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }

    #slider-range-term
        {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 1em;
        }

   .OuterTable
        {
        width:100%;
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 1px solid silver;
        }
</style>


   <script>

   window.onload=function()
  {

     var val= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:ccamt').value;
     var elePbck=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");
     var eleTem=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");
     var eleMonthPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
     var eleRates=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");   
     var a=document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:GrossSale').value;

     amttemp();
     paybackcng(val);
     MonthlyPB();
     DealDay();
     holdback();
     DayPB();
     calRate();
     grosssale();


      function grosssale()
  {

      var elePerGross=document.getElementsByClassName("PerGross");

      for(var i=0;i<elePerGross.length;i++)
       {

          elePerGross[i].value=(eleMonthPB[i].value/a).toFixed(2);


       }

  }

     function calRate()
     {

          var eleFactorPM=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorPM");

          for(var i=0;i<eleFactorPM.length;i++)
          {
              eleFactorPM[i].value=((eleRates[i].value-1)/eleTem[i].value).toFixed(2);




          }

     }   

     function DayPB()
     {
         var eleDailyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("DailyPBClass");      

         for(var i=0;i<eleDailyPB.length;i++)
         {
             eleDailyPB[i].value=(eleMonthPB[i].value/21).toFixed(2);




         }

     }

     function holdback()
      {


      var eleHoldBack=document.getElementsByClassName("HoldBackClass");
      var a= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:ccamt').value;   

       for(var i=0;i<eleHoldBack.length;i++)
       {
           eleHoldBack[i].value=(eleMonthPB[i].value/a).toFixed(2);


       }

  }

         function DealDay()
      {

      var eleDailyDays=document.getElementsByClassName("DealDays");   

       for(var i=0;i<eleDailyDays.length;i++)
       {
            eleDailyDays[i].value=(eleTem[i].value*30);

       }

  }
     function amttemp()
     {
        var eleFunded=document.getElementsByClassName("FundedClass");

        var elePayback=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");
        var eleRate=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");    

        for(var i=0;i<eleFunded.length;i++)
        {

           eleFunded[i].value=((elePayback[i].value)/(eleRate[i].value)); 

        }


     }  

      function paybackcng(val)
  {

      var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");
      var elePayback=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");


       for(var i=0;i<eleTerm.length;i++)
       {
         elePayback[i].value=(val*eleTerm[i].value);

       }

  }

      function MonthlyPB()
  {

      var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");

      var eleMonthlyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
       for(var i=0;i<eleTerm.length;i++)
       {
            eleMonthlyPB[i].value=(elePbck[i].value/eleTerm[i].value);

       }

  } 


  }
  function amount_tbl(exp,key)
  {        
        if(key=='payback'){

       var eleFunded=document.getElementsByClassName("FundedClass");
        var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");
        var eleRate=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");


        for(var i=0;i<eleFunded.length;i++)
        {

            eleFunded[i].value=((exp.value)/(eleRate[i].value));


        }
       }else{
         var eleFunded=document.getElementsByClassName("FundedClass");
        var elePayback=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");
        var eleRate=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");


        for(var i=0;i<eleFunded.length;i++)
        {

            eleFunded[i].value=((elePayback[i].value)/(exp.value));


        }
       }

   }

  function paybackchange(amt)
  {

      var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");
      var elePayback=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");


       for(var i=0;i<eleTerm.length;i++)
       {
         elePayback[i].value=(amt.value*eleTerm[i].value);

       }

  }

  function MonthlyPB(amt,key)
  {
      if(key=='Payback')
     {

      var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");

      var eleMonthlyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
       for(var i=0;i<eleTerm.length;i++)
       {
            eleMonthlyPB[i].value=(amt.value/eleTerm[i].value).toFixed(2);

       }
     }else
     {

          var eleMonthlyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
          var elePaybackClass=document.getElementsByClassName("PaybackClass");

          for(var i=0;i<eleMonthlyPB.length;i++)
          {
              eleMonthlyPB[i].value=(elePaybackClass[i].value/amt.value).toFixed(2);
          }

     }
  } 


  function FactorPM(rate,key)
  {

      if(key=='RateChange')
      {
      alert('Rate::'+key);
      var eleTerm=document.getElementsByClassName("TermClass");   
      var eleFactorPM=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorPM");
       for(var i=0;i<eleTerm.length;i++)
       {
         eleFactorPM[i].value=((rate.value-1)/eleTerm[i].value).toFixed(2);


       }
     }else
     {
         alert('Else condition::'+key+''+rate.value);

          var eleFactorPM=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorPM");
           var eleRate=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");
          for(var i=0;i<eleFactorPM.length;i++)
          {
              console.log('eleFactor'+eleRate[i].value);
              eleFactorPM[i].value=((eleRate[i].value-1)/rate.value).toFixed(2);
              console.log('Value::'+eleFactorPM[i].value);
          }

     } 
  } 

  function holdback(holdbck,key)
  {

     if(key=='holdback')
     {
     alert('Alert value'+key);
      var eleHoldBack=document.getElementsByClassName("HoldBackClass");   
      var MonthlyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
      var a= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:ccamt').value;

       for(var i=0;i<MonthlyPB.length;i++)
       {
           eleHoldBack[i].value=(MonthlyPB[i].value/holdbck.value).toFixed(2);


       }


     }else
     {

          var a= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:ccamt').value;

           var MonthlyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");

          var eleHoldBack=document.getElementsByClassName("HoldBackClass");

          for(var i=0;i<MonthlyPB.length;i++)
          {
             var t = (holdbck.value/a).toFixed(2);

              eleHoldBack[i].value=(holdbck.value/a).toFixed(2);
              console.log('Value of HOLDBACK::'+eleHoldBack[i].value);
          }





  }
 }

  function dailypb(dailypay)
  {


      var eleDailyPB=document.getElementsByClassName("DailyPBClass");   

       for(var i=0;i<eleDailyPB.length;i++)
       {
           eleDailyPB[i].value=(dailypay.value/21).toFixed(2);


       }

  }

  function Deallength(term)
  {


      var eleDailyDays=document.getElementsByClassName("DealDays");   

       for(var i=0;i<eleDailyDays.length;i++)
       {
            eleDailyDays[i].value=(term.value*30);

       }

  }

  function grosscal(grossper,key)
  {
      if(key=='monthpb')
      {

          var a=document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id16:j_id17:GrossSale').value;
          var elePerGross=document.getElementsByClassName("PerGross");
       for(var i=0;i<elePerGross.length;i++)
       {
         elePerGross[i].value=(grossper.value/a).toFixed(2);

       }

      }else
      {

        var eleMonthPB=document.getElementsByClassName("MonthlyPB");
        var elePerGross=document.getElementsByClassName("PerGross");  
        for(var i=0;i<elePerGross.length;i++)
        {
             elePerGross[i].value=(eleMonthPB[i].value/grossper.value).toFixed(2);
        }

      }

  }




  function copy_data(val){
    var b = document.getElementById(val.id).value;
    console.log('Value of b::'+b);

     document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id31:j_id32:ptest').value=b;
     }

    function factor_copy(val)
    {
        var c=document.getElementById(val.id).value;
        document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id31:j_id32:FactorRate').value=c;
        var eleRate=document.getElementsByClassName("FactorClass");

        for(var i=0;i<eleRate.length;i++)
        {
            eleRate[i].value=c;
        }
    } 
</script>





<apex:sectionHeader title="PRICING OPTIONS CALCULATOR"/>

    <table class="OuterTable customCssClass">    
    <tr>
       <td style="width:30%" valign="top">
           <!-- --------- MERCHANT DETAILS section start----------------- -->
           <apex:pageBlock title="MERCHANT DETAILS">
               <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
                     <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}" label="Legal Name" style="float:left" />
                     <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Business_DBA_Name__c}" label="DBA"/>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Fico_Requirement__c}" label="Credit Score"/>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Time_In_Business__c}" label="Years in Business"/>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Daily_Payment__c}" styleClass="DailyPayment" label="Avg. Daily Bank Balance" />
               </apex:pageblocksection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
          <!-- --------- MERCHANT DETAILS section ends----------------- -->
      </td>
       <td style="width:70%" valign="top">
         <!-- --------- OFFER USER INPUT section start----------------- -->
         <apex:pageBlock title="OFFER USER INPUT">
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" >

                <apex:inputfield value="{!objOpportunity .Program_Type__c}" />
                <apex:inputfield value="{!objOpportunity .ForecastCategoryName}"/>
                <apex:outputlabel />
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Monthly_Gross_Sales_Amount__c}" id="GrossSale" onkeyup="grosscal(this,'grossamt')"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Credit_Card_Processing_Volume_LM__c}" id="ccamt" onkeyup="holdback(this,'holdback')"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Monthly_Payment__c}"   onkeyup="paybackchange(this)"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Adjusted_Monthly_Gross_Sale__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Adjusted_Monthly_CC_Sale__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Holdback_del__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Factor_Rate__c}" onkeyup="factor_copy(this)"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Hybrid_Holdback__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Hybrid_Amount_Payment__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity .Amount_Requested__c}"  onkeyup="copy_data(this)"/>



                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/><br/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <!-- --------- OFFER USER INPUT section ends----------------- -->
       </td>    
     </tr>
     </table>
     <br/>
     <br/>

    <table style="width:100%"  class="customListTableCss">
    <!-- <tr>
    <th>  </th>
    <th> OFFERS</th>
    </tr>-->
    <tr >
       <td style="width:40%" valign="top">
       <!-- --------- PRICE CALCULATOR section start----------------- -->
           <apex:pageBlock title="PRICE CALCULATOR" > 
           <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">

         <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity.Amount_Requested__c}" id="ptest"/> 

       <!--  Amount Requested:<input type="text" id="box2" value="{!objOpportunity.Amount_Requested__c}" />-->


           <!-- <div id="slider"></div>



            <script>
               $var = "{!objOpportunity.Amount_Requested__c}";
               //alert({!objOpportunity.Monthly_Gross_Sales__c});

                $("#slider").rangeSlider({bounds:{min: 10000, max: 50000}},{defaultValues:{min:$var,max:$var }});

            </script>-->

          <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity.Factor_Rate__c}" id="FactorRate"/>
          <!--<div id="slider1"></div>
          <script>
           $var = "{!objOpportunity.Factor_Rate__c}";
            $("#slider1").rangeSlider({bounds:{min: 1, max: 9}},{defaultValues:{min: $var, max: $var}});
            </script>-->  

           <apex:inputField value="{!objOpportunity.Daily_Payment__c}"/>
           <!-- <div id="slider2"></div>
          <script>
               $var = "{!objOpportunity.Term__c}";
                $("#slider2").rangeSlider({bounds:{min: 1, max: 12}},{defaultValues:{min: $var, max: $var}});
          </script>    -->


     </apex:pageblockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
     <!-- --------- PRICE CALCULATOR section ends----------------- -->
  </td>
  <td style="width:60%" valign="top" > 
     <!-- --------- OFFERS section starts----------------- -->
        <apex:pageBlock title="OFFERS">
           <apex:pageblocktable value="{!wrap}" var="w" id="offtbl">
                <apex:column headerValue="Offer Name" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Name}" rendered="{!w.editble}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Name}" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Type" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Offer_Type__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Offer_Type__c}" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>

               <apex:column headerValue="Term(Months)" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Term_in_Months__c}"  rendered="{!w.editble}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Term_in_Months__c}" onblur="Deallength(this),MonthlyPB(this,'Term'),FactorPM(this,'Term')" styleClass="TermClass" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Funded"  >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Funded__c}"  rendered="{!w.editble}" />   
                     <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Funded__c}" styleClass="FundedClass" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Payback" >
                      <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Payback_offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Payback_offer__c}" rendered="{!!w.editble}" styleClass="PaybackClass" onblur="MonthlyPB(this,'Payback'),amount_tbl(this,'payback')"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Rate"  >
                     <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Offer_Rate__c}"  rendered="{!w.editble}" />
                     <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Offer_Rate__c}" styleClass="FactorClass"  onblur="FactorPM(this,'RateChange'),amount_tbl(this,'rate')" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="HoldBack%" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Holdback_offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Holdback_offer__c}" styleClass="HoldBackClass" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Daily PB Amount" >
                       <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Daily_PB_Amount_offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Daily_PB_Amount_offer__c}" rendered="{!!w.editble}" styleClass="DailyPBClass"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Monthly PB Amount" >
                       <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Monthly_PB_Amount_offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Monthly_PB_Amount_offer__c}" rendered="{!!w.editble}" styleClass="MonthlyPB" onkeyup="holdback(this,'monthpb')"  onblur="dailypb(this),grosscal(this,'monthpb')"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Deal Length(Days)">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Deal_Length_Offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                      <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Deal_Length_Offer__c}" styleClass="DealDays" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Factor per Month" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Factor_Per_Month_Offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                      <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Factor_Per_Month_Offer__c}" rendered="{!!w.editble}" styleClass="FactorPM"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="%of Gross">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Gross_Per_Offer__c}" rendered="{!w.editble}"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!w.offerwrap.Gross_Per_Offer__c}" styleClass="PerGross" rendered="{!!w.editble}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Edit"  action="{!editoffer}" reRender="offtbl" rendered="{!w.selected}">
                            <apex:param assignTo="{!opget}" value="{!w.index}" name="editid"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveoffer}" reRender="offtbl"  rendered="{!!w.selected}">&nbsp;
                         <apex:param name="saveid" value="{!w.index}" assignTo="{!opget}"/>
                  </apex:commandButton>
                   <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!canceloffer}" reRender="offtbl" immediate="true"  rendered="{!!w.selected}">
                         <apex:param assignTo="{!opget}" name="cancelid" value="{!w.index}"/>
                   </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:column>

            <br/><br/><br/>
            </apex:pageblocktable>
           <!--     <apex:pageBlock title="OFFERS">
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstoffer}" var="o">
            <apex:column headerValue="Offer Name" value="{!o.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!o.Offer_Type__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Term(Months)"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Funded" value="{!o.Cash_Wanted__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Payback" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Rate" />
            <apex:column headerValue="HoldBack%" value="{!o.WH_Withhold__c }"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Daily PB Amount" value="{!o.Reduced_UW_V_MC__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Monthly PB Amount" value="{!o.AVG_Monthly_VMC__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Deal Length(Days)" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Factor per Month"  />
            <apex:column headerValue="%of Gross" />

            <br/><br/><br/>
            </apex:pageblocktable>-->

            <!-- -------------Add button in Offer table------------------- -->
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addoffer}" immediate="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <br/>
       </apex:pageBlock>     
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that an alternative to adding a lot of client-side JavaScript is to use Visualforce's built-in partial page re-rendering. This will require less code but can feel unresponsive and so confusing to users.

If you do want to do this in JavaScript, using the raw browser [DOM methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp) tends to lead to pretty verbose and hard to follow code. Instead I suggest you add [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) to the page so that you are using a higher level of abstraction, meaning more functionality with less lines.  And jQuery's API hides the differences between browsers. Remember to include jQuery in your page; you can reference it from a [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) to get started, but adding a copy to your org as a static resource and referencing that is a more secure approach.

As an example (not what you are trying to do), this code shows and hides some labels and input fields depending on a select list (picklist) in each row of the table. Notice that there are no fragile ID values (and in any case the ID values change per table row); instead the elements are being matched based on the HTML element type (e.g. "select") and a CSS class e.g. "typeMarker") that can be added using Visualforce's `styleClass` attribute. Supporting multiple ways to select elements is one of jQuery's features. Functions like `closest` and `find` allow you to move up to parent elements or down to child elements from an element. There are lots of other helpful functions available too. jQuery allows you to add code to the browser's `onload` without overwriting anything that may have already be put there via the `ready` function.

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function showHideInRow(select) {

            var tr = select.closest('tr');

            var amountLabel = tr.find('.amountLabelMarker');
            var percentageLabel = tr.find('.percentageLabelMarker');
            var amount = tr.find('input.amountValueMarker');
            var percentage = tr.find('input.percentageValueMarker');

            var v = select.val();
            if (v === 'Percentage') {
                percentageLabel.show();
                percentage.show();
                amountLabel.hide();
                amount.hide();
            } else if (v === 'Amount') {
                amountLabel.show();
                amount.show();
                percentageLabel.hide();
                percentage.hide();
            } else {
                amountLabel.hide();
                amount.hide();
                percentageLabel.hide();
                percentage.hide();
            }
        }
        $('select.typeMarker').change(function() {
            showHideInRow($(this));
        });
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

Yes there is a learning curve, but you will get good payback on the time spent.